Ubuntu 24.04: Complete system freeze: *ERROR* GT0: Failed to reset chip
I am having issues with my Lenovo Thinkbook on Ubuntu 24.04.
It freezes randomly. Sometimes it happens multiple times an hour, sometimes only every few hours, but there is not one day where this does not happen.
If the freeze happens, the entire screen is frozen for about a minute. Then the cursor starts moving again, but that's it. I need to shut down by keeping the power button pressed every time.
I checked the logs and found the following in /var/log/syslog:
2024-09-10T11:52:35.776949+02:00 myhost gnome-shell[2996]: message repeated 3 times: [ Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x4600004]
2024-09-10T11:55:00.274528+02:00 myhost tracker-miner-fs-3[6561]: (tracker-extract-3:6561): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 11:55:00.274: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
2024-09-10T11:55:01.948795+02:00 myhost CRON[6570]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
2024-09-10T11:58:42.120191+02:00 myhost tracker-miner-fs-3[6753]: (tracker-extract-3:6753): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 11:58:42.119: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
2024-09-10T12:00:00.266698+02:00 myhost systemd[1]: Starting sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool...
2024-09-10T12:00:00.276565+02:00 myhost systemd[1]: sysstat-collect.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-09-10T12:00:00.276615+02:00 myhost systemd[1]: Finished sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool.
2024-09-10T12:00:26.541539+02:00 myhost tracker-miner-fs-3[6771]: (tracker-extract-3:6771): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 12:00:26.541: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
2024-09-10T12:00:35.453468+02:00 myhost systemd[2669]: Started snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier.service - Service for snap application firmware-updater.firmware-notifier.
2024-09-10T12:00:35.472029+02:00 myhost systemd[1]: tmp-snap.rootfs_J1jhx3.mount: Deactivated successfully.
2024-09-10T12:00:35.524196+02:00 myhost kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1725962435.522:217): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firmware-updater" name="/proc/6804/maps" pid=6804 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
2024-09-10T12:00:35.643261+02:00 myhost kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1725962435.641:218): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier" name="/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" pid=6780 comm="firmware-notifi" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
2024-09-10T12:00:35.664940+02:00 myhost dbus-daemon[1118]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.fwupd' unit='fwupd.service' requested by ':1.130' (uid=1000 pid=6780 comm="/snap/firmware-updater/127/bin/firmware-notifier" label="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier (enforce)")
2024-09-10T12:00:35.683507+02:00 myhost systemd[1]: Starting fwupd.service - Firmware update daemon...
2024-09-10T12:00:35.765097+02:00 myhost fwupd[6843]: 10:00:35.764 FuPluginUefiCapsule  SMBIOS BIOS Characteristics Extension Byte 2 is invalid -- UEFI Specification is unsupported, but /sys/firmware/efi exists: System does not support UEFI mode
2024-09-10T12:00:37.489446+02:00 myhost fwupd[6843]: 10:00:37.489 FuMain               Daemon ready for requests (locale en_GB.UTF-8)
2024-09-10T12:00:37.489874+02:00 myhost dbus-daemon[1118]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
2024-09-10T12:00:37.490060+02:00 myhost systemd[1]: Started fwupd.service - Firmware update daemon.
2024-09-10T12:00:51.609871+02:00 myhost wpa_supplicant[1174]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 7c:ff:4d:89:df:3b [GTK=CCMP]
2024-09-10T12:05:01.965640+02:00 myhost CRON[6957]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
2024-09-10T12:05:58.030406+02:00 myhost tracker-miner-fs-3[6963]: (tracker-extract-3:6963): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 12:05:58.030: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
2024-09-10T12:06:53.600368+02:00 myhost tracker-miner-fs-3[6983]: (tracker-extract-3:6983): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 12:06:53.600: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Invalid argument (g-io-error-quark, 13)
2024-09-10T12:08:19.737541+02:00 myhost systemd[2669]: Started vte-spawn-a4af0dc1-6283-4265-b086-5169bb8371a9.scope - VTE child process 7123 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 5762.
2024-09-10T12:10:17.191619+02:00 myhost systemd[1]: Starting sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool...
2024-09-10T12:10:17.202449+02:00 myhost systemd[1]: sysstat-collect.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-09-10T12:10:17.202513+02:00 myhost systemd[1]: Finished sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool.
2024-09-10T12:10:51.818945+02:00 myhost wpa_supplicant[1174]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 7c:ff:4d:89:df:3b [GTK=CCMP]
2024-09-10T12:14:45.958245+02:00 myhost kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
2024-09-10T12:14:49.278561+02:00 myhost systemd[2669]: Started app-gnome-org.gnome.Settings-7316.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
2024-09-10T12:14:49.486544+02:00 myhost gnome-shell[2996]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x4600004
2024-09-10T12:15:01.964312+02:00 myhost CRON[7366]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
2024-09-10T12:16:35.107503+02:00 myhost /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) event10 - PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
2024-09-10T12:16:44.908192+02:00 myhost kernel: Fence expiration time out i915-0000:00:02.0:Xorg[2808]:f7ee!
2024-09-10T12:16:46.368599+02:00 myhost google-chrome.desktop[4491]: [4484:4484:0910/121646.368192:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(1007)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=512
2024-09-10T12:16:50.479162+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 12:0:00000000
2024-09-10T12:16:50.479171+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: Resetting chip for stopped heartbeat on rcs0
2024-09-10T12:16:50.479172+02:00 myhost kernel: Fence expiration time out i915-0000:00:02.0:rocketchat-desk[4937]:260!
2024-09-10T12:16:50.479173+02:00 myhost kernel: Fence expiration time out i915-0000:00:02.0:rocketchat-desk[4937]:25e!
2024-09-10T12:16:50.479173+02:00 myhost kernel: Fence expiration time out i915-0000:00:02.0:rocketchat-desk[4937]:25c!
2024-09-10T12:16:50.583811+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: rcs0 reset request timed out: {request: 00000001, RESET_CTL: 00000001}
2024-09-10T12:16:50.670524+02:00 myhost kernel: message repeated 11 times: [ i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: rcs0 reset request timed out: {request: 00000001, RESET_CTL: 00000001}]
2024-09-10T12:16:50.670534+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: Failed to reset chip
2024-09-10T12:16:50.671206+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm:add_taint_for_CI [i915]] CI tainted:0x9 by intel_gt_reset+0x2f0/0x390 [i915]
2024-09-10T12:16:50.673207+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: Failed to reset GuC, ret = -110
2024-09-10T12:16:50.777708+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: rcs0 reset request timed out: {request: 00000001, RESET_CTL: 00000001}
2024-09-10T12:16:51.207752+02:00 myhost /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "ACR", prod id 1905
2024-09-10T12:16:51.207785+02:00 myhost /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
2024-09-10T12:16:51.207794+02:00 myhost /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
2024-09-10T12:16:51.207801+02:00 myhost /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
2024-09-10T12:16:51.207811+02:00 myhost /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  148.50  1920 2008 2052 2200  1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz 
eP)
2024-09-10T12:16:51.207820+02:00 myhost /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2808]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  174.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1119 +hsync -vsync (83.9 kHz e)

Another crash led to the following log:
2024-10-07T09:10:07.949925+02:00 myhost systemd[1]: Starting sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool...
2024-10-07T09:10:07.954356+02:00 myhost systemd[1]: sysstat-collect.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-10-07T09:10:07.954563+02:00 myhost systemd[1]: Finished sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool.
2024-10-07T09:12:20.200564+02:00 myhost kernel: Fence expiration time out i915-0000:00:02.0:chrome[4470]:2165e!
2024-10-07T09:12:22.911121+02:00 myhost google-chrome.desktop[4377]: [4370:4370:1007/091222.910755:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(980)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=512
2024-10-07T09:12:23.055034+02:00 myhost google-chrome.desktop[4377]: [9350:9350:1007/091223.054883:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
2024-10-07T09:12:26.239549+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 12:0:00000000
2024-10-07T09:12:26.239558+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: Resetting chip for stopped heartbeat on rcs0
2024-10-07T09:12:26.240536+02:00 myhost kernel: Fence expiration time out i915-0000:00:02.0:chrome<4470>:2165c!
2024-10-07T09:12:26.240540+02:00 myhost kernel: Fence expiration time out i915-0000:00:02.0:chrome<4470>:21662!
2024-10-07T09:12:26.240541+02:00 myhost kernel: Fence expiration time out i915-0000:00:02.0:chrome<4470>:21660!
2024-10-07T09:12:26.344112+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: rcs0 reset request timed out: {request: 00000001, RESET_CTL: 00000001}
2024-10-07T09:12:26.430783+02:00 myhost kernel: message repeated 11 times: [ i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: rcs0 reset request timed out: {request: 00000001, RESET_CTL: 00000001}]
2024-10-07T09:12:26.430786+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: Failed to reset chip
2024-10-07T09:12:26.431470+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm:add_taint_for_CI [i915]] CI tainted:0x9 by intel_gt_reset+0x2f0/0x390 [i915]
2024-10-07T09:12:26.433552+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: Failed to reset GuC, ret = -110
2024-10-07T09:12:26.538078+02:00 myhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* GT0: rcs0 reset request timed out: {request: 00000001, RESET_CTL: 00000001}
2024-10-07T09:12:26.541843+02:00 myhost google-chrome.desktop[4377]: [9350:9350:1007/091226.541436:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 2 times!

I tried switching between wayland and X11, this did not change anything.
Output of lshw -C display:
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1200 resolution=1920,1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:189 memory:601c000000-601cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff

Output of uname -a:
Linux myhost 6.8.0-41-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug  2 20:41:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Output of lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble


EDIT ------------------------------------------------------------
What I tried so far:

Setting i915.enable_guc in grub
Based on similar questions:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-6.5/+bug/2058750/comments/8
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/14zifl8/comment/jrzbdvb/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button
I tried with all possible values (0,1,2,3)
Without any positive outcome!

Setting i915.enable_psr2_sel_fetch=0
Based on this question:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2483059
Without any positive outcome!


